# Testing the hypothesis with R.

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification

Test the hypothesis:
additional work affects productivity of yields, i.e. g.

The test data is defined as:(Without additional work / with additional work)
$\
93.8;88
99;95.2
95.4;86
80.8;77
86.7;88.5
98.3;94.5
98.6;94.9
94.6;88.3
89;93.1
95.7;95
97.2;91.7
96.7;82.8
90.3;90.8
85.8;79.5
95.9;81
91.3;89$

I tried to solve this task with R:

```
> a = c(93.8,99,95.4,80.8,86.7,98.3,98.6,94.6,89,95.7,97.2,96.7,90.3,85.8,95.9,91.3)
> b = c(88,95.2,86,77,88.5,94.5,94.9,88.3,93.1,95,91.7,82.8,90.8,79.5,81,89)
> var.test(a,b, var.equal=TRUE, alt="greater")

    F test to compare two variances

data:  a and b
F = 0.82018, num df = 15, denom df = 15, p-value = 0.647
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is greater than 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3412518       Inf
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
         0.8201807
```

The $ p-value $ is greater than $ .05 $ si I can't reject the $H_{0}$ hypothesis that $ \mu = \mu_{0}$. 
Is this correct?

Comment: Lots of issues here.  If you are testing $μ_b=μ_a$ and you think both are normally distributed then you might consider using a two-tailed $t$-test, but not a one-tailed variance test.  Whether you regard the data as paired or unpaired and in the latter case whether you assume they have the same variance is something else to think about

Comment: So it should be something like : $
t.test(a,b, var.equal=FALSE, alt="two.sided")
$?

Comment: @Henry and then I see that $p-value = 0.02583 $ is less than $.05$?, so I can reject the null hypothesis

Comment: Something like that, yes

Comment: @Henry Ok, thank you